# NameError Handling in Python

Tags: python, exception, nameerror

I am new to python and I had some difficulty to understand why the {try... except} worked well with below code:

```py
try:
   print(x)
except NameError:
   print('variable x is not defined')
```

but it did not work with the below code:

```py
def divide(x, y):
    try:
        result = x / y
    except (ZeroDivisionError, NameError):
        print("division by zero!")
    except NameError:
        print('only numeric values')
    else:
        return result
        # print("result is", result)

print(divide(4,f))
```

Comment: Both `x` and `y` will always be defined inside the function when you set them as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few problems in your code.

As is, `NameError` would be raised by:

```
print(divide(4,f))
```

because there is no `f`.

You would have to handle the exception where it's raised, i.e.:

```
try:
    print(divide(4,f))
except NameError:
    print('variable f is not defined')
```

Now when you look into the function itself, this line:

```
except (ZeroDivisionError, NameError):
```

means the following block gets executed when either `ZeroDivisionError` **or** `NameError` is raised. So the following:

```
except NameError:
```

never gets to play. And the message sort of suggest you were perhaps looking for something like `TypeError`. E.g. when you wanted a number, but got for instance a `str`.

And `NameError` essentially meaning variable not defined, you would never (OK, unless you `del` it) see it accessing `x` or `y` in a function that accepts these two as arguments. You could see `TypeError` calling it without an expected positional argument, but in that function `x` and `y` will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat difficult to see (you should fix the formatting of the code sections):

In the second example the name error will occur in the line calling the divide function, which is outside any exception handler.